# query builder add condition on field type array

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

My question is simple : is it possible to add a where statment using doctrine and the query builder on a field type array ?

Inside my entity I have the following :

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="weekDays", type="array")
 */
private $weekDays;
```

In the object view the array look like this:

```
array(
  1 => false,
  2 => false,
  3 => true,
  4 => false,
  5 => false,
  6 => false,
  7 => false
);
```

an it's representation once serialize and inserted into the database look like this :

```
a:7:{i:1;b:0;i:2;b:0;i:3;b:1;i:4;b:0;i:5;b:0;i:6;b:0;i:7;b:0;}
```

What I try to achieve is something like this :

```
   $q = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Notification')
        ->createQueryBuilder('n')
        ->andWhere('e.weekDays = :day')    <-- This is wrong
        ->setParameter('day', date('N'))
    ;
```

typically this would result to something like this in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM notification WHERE weekDays LIKE '%i:1;b:1%' -- if date('N') = 1 (monday)
SELECT * FROM notification WHERE weekDays LIKE '%i:7;b:1%' -- if date('N') = 7 (sunday)
```

and 
    SELECT * FROM notification WHERE weekDays LIKE '%i:1;b:0%'
in case I want to set `->andWhere('e.weekDays != :day')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using version 2.5 of doctrine and 3.0+ of symfony it might look something like:

```
$qb = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Notification')
    ->createQueryBuilder('n');
$qb->where($qb->expr()->like('n.weekDays',':weekDays'))
    ->setParameter('weekDays','%i:'.date('N').';b:1%');
$results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**Older methods that may also work:**

```
$q = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Notification')
    ->createQueryBuilder('n')
    ->andWhere("e.weekDays LIKE '%:day%'")
    ->setParameter('day', 'i:'.date('N').';b:1')
;
```

If you wanted to structure your data a little different you could separate that field into 7 since weekdays are not going to change:

```
//Entity
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
 protected $monday;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
 protected $tuesday;

//And so on
```

Then something like:

```
$weekday = strtolower(date('l')); //Lowercase "L"
$q = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Notification')
    ->createQueryBuilder('n')
    ->andWhere('n.'.$weekday. '= 1');
```

Comment: I was thinking about something more object-oriented, but I don't even know if doctrine implement something like this. I'll let others have a chance to propose something before accepting your answer but it definitively help :)

Comment: I added another possibility