# Symfony findOneBy: column type array returns null

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have an entity with a column type array

```
/**
 * Report entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="report")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ReportRepository")
 */
class Report
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="selectedCountries", type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    private $selectedCountries;
```

In the database I have a a record which is stored as:

```
+-------------------------+
|    selectedCountries    |
+-------------------------+
|         a:0:{}          |
+-------------------------+
```

When I do:

```
$report = $this->reportRepository->findOneBy(array('selectedCountries' => []));
```

I get null and I have no idea why.

The db connection, entity, repository etc.. is working fine: just when I include this array in the findOneBy() it does not find the result.

Comment: You should enable `general_log_file` and see how the query looks like. Based on that, you might need to create a custom  `findOneByArrayColumn` method to change the default query.

Comment: With findBy I'm not sure, but using a custom query like this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640234/query-builder-add-condition-on-field-type-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the [Symfony profiler](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-web-debug-toolbar-and-profiler-enhancements), I debugged the queries doctrine makes and found that I need to use `simple_array` instead of `array` for the `@ORM\Column type`.

When I use array as a column type: doctrine serializes this array whenever it saves data to the database like `a:0:{}`. The problem with this approach is when I try to run a findby:

- If I use an array as a parameter, doctrine querie looks like this: `..AND t0.selectedCountries IN ('de')..`
- If I use a serialized array, doctrine escapes it like this: `..AND 
  t0.selectedCountries = 's:19:\"a:1:{i:0;s:2:\"de\";}\";' ..`

So in both cases the record will not be found!

But by using `simple_array` doctrine query looks like: `.. AND t0.selectedCountries IN ('de') ..` which is perfect since the data in the table is saved now as:

```
+-------------------------+
|    selectedCountries    |
+-------------------------+
|         de              |
+-------------------------+
```

The only issue with this approach is when you have more elements in the array: `selectedCountries    => de,fr,uk` and want to search by this. For this to work you should do extra work:

Add `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` to your entity and sort the array before inserting

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setSelectedCountriesValue()
{
    sort($this->selectedCountries);
}
```

In your entity's repository use [Query Builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder) and sort the array when trying to find results.

```
 $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->select('r')
            ->from('AppBundle:Report', 'r')
            ...

        if ($creteria['selectedCountries']) {
            sort($creteria['selectedCountries']);
            $qb->andWhere('r.selectedCountries= :selectedCountries')
                ->setParameter('selectedCountries', implode(',', $creteria['selectedCountries']));
        }
```